# Using an external data source for an ETL Transformation with pentaho data integration

Tags: parsing, pentaho, etl, nosql

As part of a bigdata project, I'm working actually on a data transformation task from an external unstructured data source (a parsed data from a website for example) to a nosql database, for that i am using pentaho data integration as a tool of transformation, my question is that i want to know if there is a method for doing that (use an xml parser on a website then transform the data to a nosql database).
Thank you.

Comment: Can you please give more details on this ??..like what exactly is a data source and what exactly is the no-sql database you are using ??

Comment: thank you for your offering your help, i did some researches and i found how to do it :) thank you very much